# Link Click using selenium webdriver is giving timeout error, link is working fine on browser otherwise

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write a piece of code using Testng in selenium, the problem is when i try to click a link, the code becomes unresponsive and gives error- Timed out receiving message from renderer

Tried driver.get("https://infostore.saiglobal.com/") instead of driver.findElement(By.linkText("Infostore")).click(); still remains unresponsive - Doesnot get directed to the webpage - https://infostore.saiglobal.com/

```
@Test
public void testSai() throws Exception {

    driver.get("https://www.saiglobal.com/"); //open homepage
    driver.findElement(By.id("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept")).click(); //accept cookie
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sai-header > div > div.main-nav > div.store-box > div")).click(); //click on Login to open list
    sleep(2);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Infostore")).click(); //click on infostore to be redirected to https://infostore.saiglobal.com/
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[.='Infostore'])[2]")).click();` have you tried this? I when I  run this atleast the script is trying to access the page.

Comment: @supputuri - Yes I've tried that too. It tries to access the page but is not landing on that page and gives the same timeout error.

Comment: Page is not even loading manually.

Comment: It is loading from the browser. I just checked

Comment: Which element are you trying to identify through `#sai-header > div > div.main-nav > div.store-box > div`?

Comment: @DebanjanB - Trying to click Login to display list of items.

Comment: @SSharma This information is missing in your question. Can you update the question accordingly along with the desired output?

Comment: @DebanjanB: Please read the comments below. The issue was resolved with a wrokaround. The problem is in the next webpage now for which I opened up new thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349633/timeout-error-when-an-element-is-clicked-in-selenium

Comment: @SSharma Okay, good to know that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190669/discussion-between-ssharma-and-debanjanb).

Comment: @SSharma You are still beating around the bush, can you straight away mention in your question `trying to click Login to display list of items` in addition to your code comments?

Comment: @DebanjanB - The "Login " element performs well and is not causing issue. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have checked this issue and there is an workaround for this issue if you wish to have this.Try following code.

1. Take the `href` attribute value from the link element.
2. Delete all cookies.
3. driver.navigate().to(URL);

   public static void main(String[] args){

   ```
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "\\Executables\\Chromedriver.exe");
       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
       Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
       driver.get("https://www.saiglobal.com/");       
       driver.findElement(By.id("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept")).click();
       WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='desktop-login']")));
       actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
       WebElement element1=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='desktop-login']/ul/li/a[contains(text(),'Infostore')]")));
       String str1=element1.getAttribute("href");
       driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
       driver.navigate().to(str1);
       System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
   ```

   }

Comment: This is indeed redirecting to new page but timeout comes for System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

Comment: I'm using Chrome Browser

Comment: Tried using mozilla too. still not working. However, it works fine if I do manually

Comment: Hello, it did redirect to the page but same timeout problem on this page as well. Have opened new thread for that

Comment: Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
driver.get("https://www.saiglobal.com/");    driver.findElement(By.id("CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept")).click();
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='desktop-login']")));
actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
WebElement element1=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='desktop-login']/ul/li/a[contains(text(),'Infostore')]")));
String str1=element1.getAttribute("href");
driver.navigate().to(str1);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349633/timeout-error-when-an-element-is-clicked-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error with Selenium that the developers have been dealing with for over a year. They never really give a concrete answer as to what causes it or how to fix it.

The first port of call would be to make sure that your browser and Selenium are compatible. Try opening a different URL that you know works, and if the error persists then there is likely an error with the compatibility of your selenium and web browser. If it works, then there is something wrong with your website.

For reference, I opened your website using Python Selenium, and had no issues loading or interacting with elements. So the error is local to the software you are using.

The issue can also be caused by sleeps(no idea why), so try removing any sleeps and see if this stops the issue.

Comment: I've been using same browser for testing other sites, it works fine. there's something fishy about this particular site. For example - I've trying to access this a page using  driver.get("https://infostore.saiglobal.com/en-au/Standards/ISO-9001-2015-586896_SAIG_ISO_ISO_1344248/"); this also goes unresponsive